# Odd digit count python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task is to find the number of odd numbers in an integer.

```
count_odd_digits(n):
```

Given a non-negative integer, count how many digits of it are odd numbers.

example:

```
count_odd_digits(123450) → 3 #digits    1,3,    and 5   are odd
```

I have so far:

```
def count_odd_digits(n):

    ans = 0
    for i in str(n):    
        if int(n) %2 == 1:
            ans += 1
        elif n[i]==0:
            return None
```

But I am still failing my tests, what is going wrong in my code?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: You're doing `int(n)` instead of `int(i)`. Also, your `elif` statement is complete and utter nonsense.

Comment: To clarify, the first time the code gets to that `elif`, it will check whether `123450['2']` is equal to zero. This is why single-letter variable names are frowned upon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several problems:

- `elif n[i] == 0: return None` is completely useless.  You never want to return `None`; you just want to continue.  Since all you are doing is continuing, it can just be removed.
- `if int(n) % 2 == 1` is testing the wrong thing.  You want to check `int(i)`, not `int(n)`.

Change the code to this:

```
def count_odd_digits(n):
    ans = 0
    for i in str(n):
        if int(i) % 2:
            ans += 1
    return ans
```

It would be easier to use a generator expression:

```
def count_odd_digits(n):
    return sum(int(i) % 2 for i in str(n))
```

Comment: or just `sum(int(i)%2 for i in str(n))`

Comment: @zondo nice. I was coming on here to put the "obligatory one liner". But I see you have it right there. hehe. :) +1

Comment: That `lambda` version is pointless as well as [against PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: And you don't have a list comprehension there; there's no `list` being created. That is a generator expression.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: That is true that it is pointless; I just thought it looked nicer to have one line.  To go against PEP-8, however, is going too far, so I have removed it.

Comment: You can put it on one line if you want, as demonstrated in the linked PEP-8 section that recommends against named `lambda` functions.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yeah, but that just seems like cheating.  It's easier to read in two lines.

Comment: @zondo thanks! this fixed my problems. Just one question though, you have "if int(i)%2:" how come the code still works when you don't have a statement   after the semicolon? ex.  if int(i) %2 == 1:

Comment: @Jessica: In an `if` statement, you just need `if` and then a test.  `int(i) % 2)` will come up with either 0 or 1.  0 has a boolean value of False, and 1 has a boolean value of True.  You don't need to compare them to anything because they already have True or False values.  It is the same with any object.  With strings, `""` if False and anything else is True.  With lists, `[]` is False and anything else is True.  Same thing with tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Change int(n) to int(i)

```
def count_odd_digits(n):
    ans = 0
    for i in str(n):    
        if int(i) %2 == 1:
            ans += 1
    return ans
```

Comment: @MSeifert Sorry if you think so. But, this wasn't intentional at all. I just wanted to give most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `return None` part will immediatly terminate your function. Also you should convert `i` to an `integer` not the complete string.

A working function could look like this:

```
def count_odd_digits(n):
    ans = 0
    for i in str(n):    
        if int(i) %2 == 1:
            ans += 1
        # drop the elif part
    # return after the for loop
    return ans

count_odd_digits(123450)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to avoid converting to strings at all, and only use integers:

```
def count_odd_digits(n):
    ans = 0
    while n:
        digit = n % 10
        if digit % 2:
            ans += 1
        n //= 10 
    return ans
```